# Custom Layout not Displaying at all - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-custom-view

I am going through a code in order to display a custom view (circle draw) on a Camera preview. It builds fine with no Errors but problem is that Custom view is not showing. **I am perhaps making a mistake in integrating the Custom view in Main Activity or in XML, but cannot figure it out. Need expert opinion on that, Thank you**

> Main Activity - Starting camera and integrate Custom view on it

```
public class AndroidVideoCaptureExample extends Activity {
private Context myContext;
private FrameLayout cameraPreview;
private boolean cameraFront = false;
private int desiredwidth=640, desiredheight=360;
private MyDrawing md;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    md = (MyDrawing)findViewById(R.id.Drawing);

    myContext = this;
    initialize();
    }
}
```

> CustomView Class - To draw circle on Camera preview

```
public class MyDrawing extends View {

Canvas canvas;
private static final int DEFAULT_CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.RED;

private int circleColor = DEFAULT_CIRCLE_COLOR;
private Paint paint;

public MyDrawing(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init(context, null);
}



public MyDrawing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int w = getWidth()/2;
    int h = getHeight()/2;

    int pl = getPaddingLeft();
    int pr = getPaddingRight();
    int pt = getPaddingTop();
    int pb = getPaddingBottom();

    int usableWidth = w - (pl + pr);
    int usableHeight = h - (pt + pb);

    int radius = Math.min(usableWidth, usableHeight) / 2;
    int cx = pl + (usableWidth / 2);
    int cy = pt + (usableHeight / 2);

    paint.setColor(circleColor);
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
}
}
```

> Layout XML - A Camera Preview with custom preview on it

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="504dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <com.javacodegeeks.androidvideocaptureexample.MyDrawing
        android:id="@+id/Drawing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="534dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
       />

</FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to provide also an `onMeasure()` method?

Edit:
You're creating a custom view, so you should tell the Android system how to measure it.

Put `onMeasure()` inside your `MyDrawing` class.

To make sure it's a cause of the problem, log these values:

```
int w = getWidth()/2;
int h = getHeight()/2;
```

Comment: The circle drawn is of half the width of canvas.  where must i put on Measure()  and why. can u plz elaborate

Comment: Will let you know as soon i try it. Hope its the solution

Comment: private void onMeasure()
    {
         w = getWidth()/2;
         h = getHeight()/2;
    };  
No effect, the custom view still not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
int w = getWidth()/2;
int h = getHeight()/2;
```

Use this:

```
int w = getMeasuredWidth()/2;
int h = getMeasuredHeight()/2;
```

This worked for me in similar case like yours. I hope it helps.